# Implementing a custom UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a custom `UIView` that mimics the behavior of `UIScrollView` for some reason. And the question is how can I show the proper part of the content which is represented by the `contentOffset` property?

I've analyzed `UIScrollView` and found that it doesn't adopt any inbetween sublayers or manipulate the bounds and transform properties to apply the offset. I've overridden the UIView``'s `drawRect:` method as follows but it didn't work:

```
- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)rect {
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -content_offset_.x, -content_offset_.y);
}
```

So my question is how does `UIScrollView` show the proper part of its content? Should I override the layer's display method or else? Any suggestions would be appreciated! And please don't ask 'why do you want to do anything like that in the first place?' :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIScrollView` changes its bounds (it moves the origin around).

`-drawRect:` is called to draw your layer's content and does not affect sublayers. You're not drawing anything.

I'd just use a `UIScrollView` though. What are you doing that `UIScrollView` doesn't?

Comment: Oh.. you're right. I'd tested it and I thought it didn't change the bounds property but I was wrong. I'm making something similar to the built-in photo app but a UIScrollView inside another UIScrollView sometimes behaves very awkwardly so I wanted to make a custom one. Thanks for the answer!